# How to deploy from Bot Framework Composer in Functions Apps

Tags: azure, azure-functions, botframework, bot-framework-composer

I alredy created a chatbot, I deployed it using App Services and Azure Bot, now I want to use Function app for deployment but I only found old documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Setup the `Publish Configuration` if we want to publish our bot using the bot composer. The process to the further steps of publishing, we need to create a bot.
Follow the below steps to create and publish the bot.

[image]

Click on publication and fill with relevant details.

[image]

We need to have a bot emulator to test the bot.

[image]

Download the bot emulator and open it.

[image]

[image]
After downloading the emulator perform the configuration and proceed with the testing.

[image]

If you receive any error while testing, change the platform from 32bit to 64 bits under the configuration tab.

This completes the publishing of the bot using function app.

Before performing publishing, we need to process the profiling. Check the link for profiling [procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-publish-bot?tabs=v2x).